# Remove Windows Frame - Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a background in my installer and i was wondering that it would be a good idea to remove the windows frame from it and kept only the background and the footer buttons.

It´s possible in Inno Setup to remove Windows frame from installer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `BorderStyle` property of your [`WizardForm`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TWizardForm) to [`bsNone`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TFormBorderStyle) to make it borderless. The best place to do so is the [`InitializeWizard`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard) event method:

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
end;
```